# Using file_get_contents for multiple sites with same content

Tags: php

I want to grab a code from some websites (all of them have the same content but some of them have downtime).

So i want to make a code that checks the first site and if the code was found show it, if not check the second site etc.
The code that i have is this:

```
$website1 = file_get_contents("http://exemplesite1.com");
preg_match("' src=\"(.*?)\" type='si", $website1, $body);
$decoded_url = $body[1]; 

if ( $decoded_url == "" ) { 
$website2 = file_get_contents("http://exemplesite2.com");
preg_match("' src=\"(.*?)\" type='si", $website2, $body);
$decoded_url2 = $body[1]; 
} elseif ...
```

Here i'm blocked, i have like 6 sites, i want to do this untill it finds the code i need.

Comment: You need to learn about loops...

Answer (score 0):

Put the websites in an array, and loop through that. Assuming you only need the first one, you can exit the loop upon finding a match. Something like this:

```
$websites = ['http://exemplesite1.com', 'http://exemplesite2.com', ...];

foreach($websites as $website) {
    preg_match("' src=\"(.*?)\" type='si", $website, $body);
    $decoded_url = $body[1]; 

    if (! empty($decoded_url)) //found proper match
    break;
}
```